# Deploying *.ear file onto Liferay (JBoss) - portlets not exposed

Tags: java, deployment, liferay, portlet, ear

I'm trying to deploy .EAR on Liferay (running on JBoss), I put .EAR to JBoss deployments folder. My structure is:

- lib (some libraries/modules)
- META-INF
- WAR (it contains all Liferay specific libraries from auto deploy)
- JAR

According to console, deploy is correct. JAR is running (I have some methods with Timers and they are working properly). But I don't see any portlets from WAR that I can add, but according to console WAR is deployed. They are simply not exposed to Liferay. I know that the .EAR is like a closed structure.

I am wondering how to make portlets available to Liferay?

I would appreciate any ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no standard way to deploy portlets (WAR) inside EAR. Liferay won't detect them. Your WAR with portlets must be deployed separately.